# awk or perl to eval mathematical expressions in each line

Tags: awk, math, eval

I want a script to make awk to become an interactive mathematical calculator, to eval mathematical expressions given in each line.

I.e., instead of constructing awk commands to calculate expressions like the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 180/1149}'
0.156658

$ awk 'BEGIN{print (150+141)/1149}'
0.253264
```

I want my script to take my mathematical expressions as input and do the calculation interactively. So the session will look like (alternative of input and output):

```
180/1149
0.156658
(150+141)/1149
0.253264
1 + 2
3
2 * 3 - 5
1
```

However I'm not able to do that myself:

```
$ awk '{print}'
180/1149
180/1149
^C

$ awk '{print $0}'
180/1149
180/1149
1 + 2
1 + 2
^C
```

If there is no simple solution to awk, what else, like perl?

Comment: Why not use `bc`? or `calc` or `dc`? For the most complex equations, you can go to `axiom` or `maxima`.

Comment: I only need that once every blue moon (likely once every 10 years), so I prefer a simple script for the tools I use, rather than installing something that I'll never use again @WhiteOwl.

Comment: then `bc` is your choice.

Comment: Or if using `zsh` as your shell (why would one use any other shell ;-) ?), use its `zcalc` autoloadable function.

Comment: See [how-to-coerce-awk-to-evaluate-string-as-math-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156761/how-to-coerce-awk-to-evaluate-string-as-math-expression), especially if you need this functionality as part of a larger awk script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arithmetic evaluation is done as part of the `awk`/`perl` language evaluation. `perl` has a `eval` to evaluated arbitrary strings as perl code at runtime, so you can do:

```
perl -lne 'print eval $_'
```

But `awk` doesn't (though in the case of GNU `awk`, its debugger does, see below), so you'd need to run `awk` for each line of input, and pass the contents of that line inside the code argument for instance using GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -I CODE awk -- 'BEGIN{print(CODE)}'
```

You could also do:

```
sed 's/.*/BEGIN{print(&)}/' | awk -f -
```

To run one `awk` to interpret all the code lines, but `awk` would only start evaluating it upon reaching the end of input, so can't be used interactively. You'd be able to reuse results from a past evaluation like in `perl` though. Like on:

```
a = 3+4
a*2
```

It would print `7`, then `14`.

---

### Using gawk's debugger

`awk` has a debugger mode which has an `eval` to which you can pass awk code to interpret, so you could hijack that with something like:

```
sed -u 's/["\\]/\\&/g;s/.*/eval "print(&)"/' | gawk -D -f /dev/null
```

Comment: I was trying to use awk ->system -> sprintf -> awk, but ran out of level of quotes.

Comment: _"but awk would only start evaluating it upon reaching the end of input, so can't be used interactively"_ yeah, so I found while trying the two proposed solutions. So perl is the only solution. It works with manually input expressions, but when I tried middle-click in my terminal to past in expressions I copied elsewhere (say `1+2`), I'm getting `^[[200~1+2` as input in perl. Is that sovable?

Comment: @xpt, that sounds like your terminal's bracketed paste. It must have been enabled by mistake (modern shells  enable that but only for their own line  editor  and should disable it when running commands). See [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118). Try `printf '\e[?2004l'` to disable it.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas, will look into that. Meanwhile I found _using gawk's debugger_ is the answer for me, as it even works with pasting in expressions I copied elsewhere.

Comment: @xpt,that `\e[200~` should be independent of whether you use `perl` or `awk`. Neither would go out of their way to tell the terminal to enable bracketed paste.

Comment: @EdMorton, but like JJaoa's approach here, that runs an awk that runs one shell invocation that runs one awk invocation for every line. You don't need either shell nor that extra awk, `xargs` here is much simpler (and dedicated to run command) and runs one awk per line without needing a shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas right, I understand that, but having an `eval`-like function you can call as part of a larger awk script can be useful. I actually meant to post [that reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740846/awk-or-perl-to-eval-mathematical-expressions-in-each-line/740847?noredirect=1#comment1407222_740846) under the question, not under your answer. I've moved it now.

Comment: save 8 characters with `perl -ple\$_=eval`

Answer (score 6):

Interactively, just use [bc](/questions/tagged/bc)

---

Non-interactively, if you want to script the evaluation of the expressions:

```bash
$ cat file
180/1149
(150+141)/1149
1 + 2
2 * 3 - 5

$ bc < file
.15665796344647519582
.25326370757180156657
3
1
```

To interleave the input and output, we can use [paste](/questions/tagged/paste)

```bash
$ paste -d '\n' file <(bc < file)
180/1149
.15665796344647519582
(150+141)/1149
.25326370757180156657
1 + 2
3
2 * 3 - 5
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it with perl!

---

...or we can also use awk. Consider the following (second order) awk script `run-in-awk`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ system( "awk 'BEGIN{print " $0 "}' ") }
```

after `chmod +x run-in-awk` we are in fact asking awk to run awk

```
$ run-in-awk example
0.156658
0.156658
0.253264
0.253264
3
3
1
1
```

It also works with stdin keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

Why only awk or perl when we can use sh with awk?

```bash
#!/bin/sh
while read e_x__p_ress_ion___; do
    awk "BEGIN{print ${e_x__p_ress_ion___}}"
done
```

This will read an expression and save it into a variable. Then awk print is called and variable is passed. This is an infinite loop that exits on control-c.

Such a weird variable name is used to protect the script from changing other scripts' variables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You may want to read [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: I don't understand your *"Such a weird variable name is used to protect the script from changing other scripts' variables"*. Can you clarify and give an example where using a variable called `$expression` would be a problem for instance?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas for example when you use it in another script with its own variable `$expression`. i highly doubt that somebody will use this in a script but the chance is not zero

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas but `read` saves everything on the line into one variable if only one variable is passed so there is no difference

Comment: Try on an expression such as `length("\\") * 2` to see why you need `-r`. The missing `IFS=` would not be a problem as long as `$IFS` otherwise contains its default value.